# MongoDB sum with aggregate

Tags: php, mongodb

I am not able get sum of `ammount` column. it returns `null`.
trying to group it by date.

```
Array
(
[_id] => MongoId Object
    (
        [$id] => 5500a655642c87d663b7acd9
    )

[0] => 1
[id] => 1
[1] => 5
[site_id] => 5
[2] => 7
[ammount] => 7
[3] => 2
[status] => 2
[4] => 2012-07-04
[date] => 2012-07-04
)
```

my PHP code is here.

```
  $outt = $db->command (
        array( 
            "aggregate" => "tests",
            "pipeline" => 
                array( 
                    array( '$match' => array('$and' => array(
                                                    array( 'date' => $date ),
                                                    array('$or'=>$sites)))),
                    array( 
                            '$group' => array(
                              '_id' => '$date',
                             'sum' => array('$sum' => '$ammount')
                            )
                        )
                )
        )
    );
```

if i put `$ammount` as `_id` it displays `ammount` without `sum`.

(P.S. column name `$ammount` is correct)

Comment: you are filtering by date and some other thing first - are you sure there are any documents left to add up?

Comment: Yes there are documents matching it

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB wasn't able to return sum cause ammount was stored as string.
i converted it to double and it worked.

Mongo doesn't return any Error for it